# Wifi wireless driver doesn't exit

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, openwrt

Recently I've installed OpenWrt in my router TP-Link TL-MR3220 which [is supported](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-mr3420).

Also, I've read [about wireless](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless), that by default wireless is OFF. You can turn it on in the /etc/config/wireless by changing disabled 1 to disabled 0.

But checking the /etc/config/ folder I can't find wireless config file, besides that I've tested with `wifi detect`, but it returns me:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# wifi detect
ls: /sys/class/ieee80211: No such file or directory
```

How to turn it on my wireless card?

Comment: Have you tried to simply create the file yourself?

Comment: yes, i do but it doesn't work

Comment: If you create the file do you still get the error where it says its unable to find the file?  If so then the file isn't in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

I've reset my openwrt using this guide

[Failsafe](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe)http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe

After that my router has been enable to detect the proper driver.